# Concrete method in interface c#

Tags: c#, .net

As I know I cannot create a concrete method in an interface in c# it should give me an error
but when I Do That

```
interface IPerson
{
    void x();
    public void y()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome From Interface");
    }
}

class Teacher : IPerson
{
    public void x()
    {

    }
}
```

And in the main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IPerson p = new Teacher();
        p.y();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

the output became => Welcome From Interface
Why it did not give me an error?

Comment: total anti-pattern in my opinion.  this feature should not exist.  basically it shows microsoft lack of creativity.  it compensates for the lack of a mechanism for type composition on single inheritance model used by .net

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I agree. I agree so much that I say it in comment: code in an interface type, it's an abomination, not even a trait nor multiple-inheritance.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro in C++ there is multiple implementation inheritance, that is missing from C#. however that features is controversial, it is really helpful in certain situations. this feature aims to fill that request. in other languages it is called as mixins if that helps. its a common feature amongst languages not an anti-pattern

Comment: @DanielLeiszen i agree C# needs type composition but it is an architectural mishap to change the concept of Interface for an implementation it is basically an oxymoron

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro there is no such thing as interface. Abstract class, interface these are just vtables, serve the same purpose to help you organize your code to make sense from an OOP point of view. In C++ there is no interface only abstract class which you may or may not provide default implementation. The interface was needed in C# because without it you could only create tree like inheritance structures but it was definitely lacking default implementation for a long time. Try to understand the purpose first before you judge.

Comment: @DanielLeiszen sounds great but very inaccurate.  In my case interfaces serve as contracts to enforce loosely coupling disparate systems, not just a mere code organizing artifacts like partial classes.  Also this is not C++ is C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This feature is new in C# 8 and is called [Default implementations in interfaces](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/).

Basically you can provide an implementation of a method inside an interface that gets "inherited" by the class that implements it.

Note that the default implementation can only access other members in the interface, and you cannot declare state other than that the interface has properties. A typical usecase is when you provide overloads that all end up chaining into one common overload, perhaps the one with the most parameters.

This makes it easier to implement an interface, but it also makes it possible to tuck on more members in an interface, without having to recompile the assemblies providing types that implement them and without having to add those methods to those types.

Note that the class that implements the interface can still implement the member. You will then have *that* implementation instead. Note that this is **not** inheritance, so you cannot call `base.y()` from your method that is implemented in the class, to call the default implementation in the interface. The default implementation is used, unless you provide an actual implementation in the class, then that implementation completely replaces the default implementation from the interface.

Another detail is that the methods are only available you have a variable of the interface type, not of the concrete type.

So while this works:

```
IPerson p = new Person();
p.y();
```

this doesn't:

```
var p = new Person(); // p is now of type Person
p.y(); // CS1061 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'y' and no accessible extension method 'y' could be found
```

Since you already have a very good and short example in your question I won't add more code here, unless you ask for clarifications on some other details.